# I need to show for a moment the "drawerlayout" when the user enters a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

What I want is to show the bar that is hidden on the left, when a user enters a layout, the idea is that you know that there is that bar without having to put an icon on the actionbar that signal its existence

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you give some more in brief what exactly want you?

Comment: @PiyushGupta What I want is to show the bar that is hidden in the izqueirda, when a user enters a layout, the idea is that you know that there is that bar without having to put an icon on the actionbar that signal its existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the navigationdrawer the first time the activity is created you can simply do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_activity);

    drawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer); // the drawer itself (ListView for example)
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); // the drawer layout itself

    drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawer);
}
```

Your xml may look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/background_activity_color">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```